# Apache Pulsar topic replication with increase in cluster size

Tags: replication, apache-pulsar

I want to understand how the namespace/topic replication works in Apache Pulsar and what affect does the change in cluster size have on the replication factor of the existing and new namespaces/topics.

Consider the following scenario:

I am starting with a single node with the following broker configuration:

```
# Number of bookies to use when creating a ledger
managedLedgerDefaultEnsembleSize=1

# Number of copies to store for each message
managedLedgerDefaultWriteQuorum=1

# Number of guaranteed copies (acks to wait before write is complete)
managedLedgerDefaultAckQuorum=1
```

After a few months I decide to increase the cluster size to two with the following configuration for the new broker:

```
# Number of bookies to use when creating a ledger
managedLedgerDefaultEnsembleSize=2

# Number of copies to store for each message
managedLedgerDefaultWriteQuorum=2

# Number of guaranteed copies (acks to wait before write is complete)
managedLedgerDefaultAckQuorum=2
```

In the above scenario what will be the behaviour of the cluster:

1. Does this change the replication factor(RF) of the existing topics?
2. Do newly created topics have the old RF or the new specified RF?
3. How does the namespace/topic(Managed Ledger) -> Broker ownership work?

Please note that the two broker nodes have different configurations at this point.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are changing is the **default** replication settings (ensemble, write, ack). You shouldn't be using different defaults on different brokers, because then you'll get inconsistent behavior depending on which broker the client connects to.

The replication settings are controlled at namespace level. If you don't explicitly set them, you get the default settings. However, you can change the settings on individual namespaces using the [CLI](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/2.4.2/pulsar-admin/#set-persistence) or the REST interface. If you start with settings of (1 ensemble, 1 write, 1 ack) on the namespace and then change to (2 ensemble, 2 write, 2 ack), then the following happens:

- All new topics in the namespace use the new settings, storing 2 copies of each message
- All new messages published to existing topics in the namespace use the new settings, storing 2 copies. Messages that are already stored in existing topics are not changed. They still have only 1 copy.

An important point to note is that the number of brokers doesn't affect the message replication. In Pulsar, the broker just handles the serving (producing/consuming) of the message. Brokers are stateless and can be scaled horizontally. The messages are stored on Bookkeeper nodes (bookies). The replication settings (ensemble, write, ack) refer to Bookkeeper nodes, not brokers. Here is an diagram from the Pulsar website that illustrates this:

[image: Pulsar Architecture]

So, to move from a setting of (1 ensemble, 1 write, 1 ack) to (2 ensemble, 2 write, 2 ack), you need to add a Bookkeeper node to your cluster (assuming you start with just 1), not another broker.

Comment: Is there a way to identify a message offset to bookie(and replica) storage mapping ?

Comment: No, that level of detail is not available.